# How can I change the value of "items" with this function? It would be an example of validation using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, recursion

If the input stored in `items` is correct, then `items` remains the original value. But if the input is incorrect, it prompts the user to input new `items` and stores that value in the original `items` variable. My problem is that my code does not store the new input in the global `items` variable. I have tried using the `global` keyword to no avail. I cannot use `for/while` loops and only standard libraries.
Here is my code:

```
items = input("Please enter integers").split()
items = list(map(int, items))
    
def checksYn(p):

    if max(p) > 100 or min(p) < -100:
        new_items = input("Please enter integers between -100 and 100").split()
        new_items = list(map(int, new_items))
        checksYn(new_items)

    global items
    items = p     

print(items)
```

Comment: `checksYn` always overwrites `items` with `p`, the originally passed-in value. When it calls itself recursively, it may overwrite it with a fixed `new_items`, **but when it returns from the recursion, it will overwrite it again with `p`!.**

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! Now I understand why my program wasn´t working like expected I feel kind of dumb lol. Anyways, thank you again you´ve made me a better programmer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will solve your problem:

```
items = input("Please enter integers").split()
items = list(map(int, items))
    
def checksYn(p):
    if max(p) > 100 or min(p) < -100:
        new_items = input("Please enter integers between -100 and 100").split()
        new_items = list(map(int, new_items))
        
        return checksYn(new_items)
    else:
        return p
     
x=checksYn(items)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's design a program which works like this -

```
Please enter integers:
1 2 300

Please enter integers between -100 and 100:
1 two 3

Please enter integers between -100 and 100:
-5 1 2 three

Please enter integers between -100 and 100:
-99 1 2 3

done: [-99, 1, 2, 3]
```

We start a rough sketch of a recursive program, `main` -

```py
def main(nums):
  try:
    return validate(nums)
  except:
    return main(retry())

nums = main(init())
print(f"done: {nums}")
```

Now we just implement `init` and `retry` -

```py
def init():
  return get_user_input("Please enter integers")

def retry():
  return get_user_input("Please enter integers between -100 and 100")

def get_user_input(prompt):
  return input(f"{prompt}:\n").split()
```

And finally write `validate` -

```py
def validate(nums):
  r = []
  for x in map(int, nums):
    if x < -100 or x > 100:
      raise ValueError
    else:
      r.append(x)
  return r
```

You're all done!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation that´s a great solution! Unfortunately, I cannot use "for" loops in my program, otherwise your answer would be 100% correct.